# What are arguments against using ENUM?

Tags: mysql

We have a table `products`. There will only be three product types ever. My PM is insisting on using `ENUM` for the `product.type` column `(free, pay, voucher)`, whereas I insist on making it `product.type_id`.

What arguments should I use against using `ENUM`?

Comment: see here: [MySQL ENUM DataType](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html)

Comment: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Raphael linked, that article is a good overview of strengths and weaknesses of the `ENUM`. But let's analyze your specific case.

You're trying to add data for a product, specifically, its `type`. Right now you have three product types. But can you certainly say that there never will be a fourth type of product? Since that's extremely expensive in `ENUM`s, I'd say that's a clear vote against using them. You only ever should consider them in small, discrete sets of options, which are well-defined and unchanging. Product type is just another piece of information about your product. As such, it has no place in the column definition.

That would probably be enough, but I'd like to point out another weakness. You can't link `ENUM`s anywhere else. So, if you want to expand your system to, say, `product_groups` that are also constrained by `type`, you're stuck recreating yet another `ENUM`. Woes upon you when you have several separate tables and the powers-that-be decide you should add a fourth.

Honestly, product type, for me, is a reference table, linked into whatever depends on it by its identifier. Because sooner or later you'll have to extend it or link it somewhere else. And `ENUM`s just weren't made for that.